# Why are these flex items spaced in this way?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have made a simple flexbox [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oc5787oo/4/) To play around with all flexbox values, but stumbled upon something that I can't explain my `.item` divs are spaced out for some reason and `.grid` is automatically stretching to full height, I'm not entirely sure why this happens?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item red">a</div>
    <div class="item yellow">b</div>
    <div class="item blue">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: black;
  padding:15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: flex;
}

.grid {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  align-self: auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.red { background: red; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
.blue { background: blue; }
```

Comment: Read about `align-items` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align-items: flex-start` (set on `.grid`) causes this type of behavior. As specified in the [MDN docs](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=CSS&docset_name=CSS&path=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items.html&platform=css&repo=Main&source=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

> The CSS align-items property defines how the browser distributes space between and around flex items along the cross-axis of their container.

If you disable it, the value will be set to `stretch` by default (each flex item will be stretched to fill the container).